# Setting focus to GridView item

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I have custom collection which was bind to `GridView`. I can set the `SelectedItem` property to `GridView` but not changing the focus. I tried to use the following piece of code to get `GridViewItem` but I'm getting `null` value.

```
GridViewItem item = ResultGv.ContainerFromIndex(0) as GridViewItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to scroll the item into view beforehand. With list virtualization - there might be no container for an item - typically when it's out of the view port.

Comment: Is there a way to get hold of GrideViewItem

Comment: That's what I said - your code should work if you first call `ScrollIntoView` on your first item.

Comment: I have a follow-up question though. Why do you need that item? Usually you don't need to grab it like that.

Comment: I need  to set focus to the items.

Comment: I tried to use `GridViewItem selectItme = VideoGridView.ContainerFromIndex(0) as GridViewItem` in the method of `VideoGridView_ItemClick`,  the `selectItme` is not null. Could you show me `GridViewItem item = ResultGv.ContainerFromIndex(0) as GridViewItem` where you placed?

Comment: it's my bad I am using the code in wrong place [ scrollviewer change event] .

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest is ,after the screen loading completes, use Grid View's Method `ScrollIntoView` for scrolling to the corresponding item. Then use `FocusState.Programmatic` to focus on a particular item.